# Why tsung setdynvars not set data

Tags: xml, linux, erlang, load-testing, tsung

Tsung not want set vars from my csv file.

This my tsung config:

```
   <session name="http-example" probability="100" type="ts_http">

    <!-- full url with server name, this overrides the "server" config value -->
 <setdynvars sourcetype="file" fileid="useragent_list" delimiter=":" order="random">
                 <var name="user_agent" />
              </setdynvars>
<setdynvars sourcetype="file" fileid="ip_list" delimiter=";" order="random">
                 <var name="ip_ran" />
              </setdynvars>

  <request>

        <http url="MY_URL" method="GET" version="1.1"> <http_header name="User-agent" value="%%_user_agent%
%"/> <http_header name="X-Forwarded-For" value="%%_ip_ran%%"/> </http>
    </request>
     <thinktime value="1" random="true"></thinktime>
   </session>
```

But when start tsung
Him not set vars.
In dump:

```
Send:1499335214.965212:<0.1137.0>:GET /url HTTP/1.1
Host: myhost.com
User-Agent: %%_user_agent%%
X-Forwarded-For: %%_ip_ran%%
```

Comment: Have you given your option tag properly with file path?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the subst="true" parameter. Like this:

```
<request subst="true">  
  <http url="MY_URL" method="GET" version="1.1"> 
    <http_header name="User-agent" value="%%_user_agent%%"/> 
    <http_header name="X-Forwarded-For" value="%%_ip_ran%%"/>
  </http>
</request>
```

Also ensure delimiters are correctly defined and do not forget to specify the input files in options. An example for your case:

```
<options>
  <option name="file_server" id="useragent_list" value="/tmp/useragent_list.txt"/>
  <option name="file_server" id="ip_list" value="/tmp/ip_list.txt"/>
</options>

<sessions>
...
```